# Facebook IOS: how to force reauthenticate

Tags: iphone, facebook

I've been looking around all day and cannot find a way to force the authorize call to Facebook to force the user to login every time. 
I'm using the Facebook-ios-sdk. 
On the server side, we use https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth? ... &auth_type=reauthenticate
To force the user to reauthenticate every time the press the Facebook button. 
But on iPhone, when I call authorize on the Facebook object, it simply flash the FB app and come back to my app; never prompting. 
What is the trick ???

thanks,
Benoit

Comment: forgot to mention that I know that if I use [self authorizeWithFBAppAuth:FALSE safariAuth:FALSE]; in Facebook authorize method, I will get a pop up that always ask for the login. But is there a way to get the same behavior using the FB app or the website.